# Upload file with apollo-upload-client from nodejs

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

I saw some examples where files are uploaded from the browser. Is it somehow possible to use *apollo-upload-client* also from nodejs? According to the documentation the Upload!-variable has to be FileList, File, Blob or ReactNativeFile. I wasn't able to imitate one of those objects in nodejs. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I've uploaded file from frontend but following this just to know if it's possible to do that from backend

Comment: why using apollo client? search for already answered fetch/axios methods ... if apollo ... is it configured and running for any other query/mutation?

Comment: I wanted to develop a GraphQL-Client that already can do everything out of the box. I want to make it as easy as possible to use the client and the apollo-upload-client is already deeply integrated. You can just pass in the file as a variable and it does the magic. Right now I'm doing the multipart request with form-data, but it's not as easy.